# How can i implement offline caching article reading app in iOS?

Tags: ios, json, uitableview, uiwebview, offline-caching

I’m building an article reading app.I’m fetching the data from server in JSON format and load into UITableView and in 
UIWebView.
An article contains images,videos and text.I want to do Offline caching means,if there is no internet user can read previous loaded 
articles.I have used async thread for images.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self checkInternetConnection];
    UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,10,0,20)];
    titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    titleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    titleLabel.text = @"Story";
    [self.navigationItem setTitleView:titleLabel];

    UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    spinner.center = CGPointMake(160, 240);
    spinner.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:spinner];
    [spinner startAnimating];
    BOOL myBool = [self isNetworkAvailable];
    if (myBool)
    {
        @try {

            self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:190/255.0 green:190/255.0 blue:190/255.0 alpha:1.0];

            // for displaying the previous screen lable with back button in details view controller        UIBarButtonItem *backbutton1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil];
            [[self navigationItem] setBackBarButtonItem:backbutton1];
            _Title1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            _Author1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            _Images1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            _Details1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            _link1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            _Date1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            pageNumber=1;
            NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:ysURL];
            NSArray *ys_avatars = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
            if(ys_avatars){
                for (int j=0;j<ys_avatars.count;j++)
                {
                    [_Title1 addObject:ys_avatars[j][@"title"]];
                    [_Author1 addObject: ys_avatars[j][@"author"]];
                    [_Images1 addObject: ys_avatars[j][@"featured_img"]];
                    [_Details1 addObject:ys_avatars[j][@"content"]];
                    [_link1 addObject:ys_avatars[j][@"permalink"]];
                    NSString *newStr=[ys_avatars[j][@"date"] substringToIndex:[ys_avatars[j]        [@"date"] length]-3];
                    [_Date1 addObject:newStr];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"asd");
            }
        }
        @catch (NSException *exception) {

        }
        dispatch_queue_t downloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("downloader", NULL);
        dispatch_async(downloadQueue, ^{
            // do our long running process here
            [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:3];
            // do any UI stuff on the main UI thread
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [spinner stopAnimating];
            });
        });
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *Cellidentifier1 = @"ysTableViewCell";
    ysTableViewCell *cell1 = [tableView      dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:Cellidentifier1 forIndexPath:indexPath];
    long row = [indexPath row];
    cell1.TitleLabel1.text = _Title1[row];
    cell1.AuthorLabel1.text = _Author1[row];
    NSString *yourStoryUrl = [_Images1[indexPath.row]  stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    if(yourStoryUrl) {
        NSArray *subStringsUrl = [yourStoryUrl componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
        NSString *stripedName = [subStringsUrl lastObject];
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,  NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString* filePath =[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",stripedName]];
        NSLog(@"File Path retrieved %@", filePath);
        if(filePath) {
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
            if(image) {
                ysTableViewCell  *updateCell =(id)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                if(updateCell)
                    updateCell.ThumbImage1.image=image;
                cell1.ThumbImage1.image=image;
            } else {
                dispatch_queue_t taskQ = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
                dispatch_async(taskQ, ^{
                    NSURL *Imageurl = [NSURL URLWithString:yourStoryUrl];
                    NSData *data =  [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:Imageurl];
                    UIImage *images1 = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
                    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
                    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
                    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(images1);
                    //_imagePath =[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",stripedName]];
                    if (![imageData writeToFile:filePath atomically:NO])
                    {
                        NSLog((@"Failed to cache image data to disk"));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        NSLog((@"the cachedImagedPath is %@",filePath));
                    }
                    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        ysTableViewCell  *updateCell =(id)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                        if(updateCell)
                            updateCell.ThumbImage1.image=images1;
                        cell1.ThumbImage1.image=images1;
                    });
                });
                return cell1;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

For Offline store you have make one sqlite file, store all the details getting from JSON into database. In Database only store the file path of images and videos. Download those assets and store them in document directory.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use keyed archive(`NSKeyedArchiver/NSKeyedUnarchiver`)

Here is a [tutorial](http://nshipster.com/nscoding/)